# Issue with accessing a variable in another viewcontroller while using a hamburger menu

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, parameter-passing, swrevealviewcontroller

In a certain viewcontroller say 'viewcontroller1', on clicking a button I am setting a variable. Now I click on my hamburger button(created using SWRevealViewController) and go to another viewcontroller I want to use the value I set in viewcontroller1 in the other viewcontroller. How can I achieve this..Also, I am using swift.

Comment: is SWRevealViewController a custom subclass? Also how are you going from viewcontroller1 to viewcontroller2? Typically, you would do your setup for viewcontroller2 in `prepare(for segue:)` passing the value to the destination viewController.

Comment: No..SWRevealViewController is a 3rd party for Hamburger menu. And while using SWRevealViewController, prepare(for segue:). is not used.

Comment: How you go to another viewcontroller show your code!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a variable in App Delegate say..'myVariable'. In your 'viewcontroller1' you can set the variable as 'appDelegate.myVariable'. You can use this format to access the variable also from another viewcontroller.

Comment: Setting a variable in App Delegate should be avoided as much as possible as it creates a global state and it is considered as a bad coding practice. Ideally, the data should be passed/injected to other viewcontroller.